# Estimating Test AUC Using K-Fold CV for Imbalanced Classification Problem

Tags: r, classification, unbalanced-classes

I have an imbalanced classification problem.

I first partitioned my data into a training set (Dataset A) and a test set (Dataset B).

I then used the R package ROSE to simultaneously undersample the majority class in Dataset A and oversample the minority class. This produced a balanced set (Dataset C) which has as many rows as Dataset A.

I have trained my model on Dataset C and computed training AUC. I now want to estimate (i.e., not using Dataset B) the test AUC using k-fold cross validation. How should I best do this?

Kind regards,

Jack